# How can I navigate the VS Code Explorer & open a file via keyboard only?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm doing a code review of a project, which means cycling through all the files in it. I want to keep my hands on the keyboard but neither do I want to have to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type in the name of each file.

I've bound <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to `workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer` which enables me to easily get to the Explorer, but then I can only `explorer.openToSide`, which isn't exactly what I want. I want to be able to open them directly, full-screen even if I have other windows open.

Are there commands for this that I can bind to? I suspect this isn't a feature yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To open a file, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once you've selected it. It's bound to the `list.select` command by default. This also works for expanding / collapsing folders.

Comment: Ah, `list.select` is the command I'm looking for. I'm on a Mac, and as in Finder, `Enter` edits the file name. I've bound `CMD`+`Enter`, which is now working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: On mac you have to do what's in andrewb's comment to get the desired effect. Thanks all!

Answer (score 23):

By default on a mac you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to open the file.

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will edit the filename.

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 0):

After `workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer` you can press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate through file list while File explorer is fosuced. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the selected file.

Also I set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> for `workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer`.

In my case, sequential navigating through list of files is a repeating sequence of these shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- <kbd>Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- ...
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- <kbd>Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- ...